# How proper change the format of date on Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

We've an eloquent model, but we want all date be on format `'Y-m-d'` instead `'U'`, something like:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'contract_date',
    'contract_end'
];

/**
 * The storage format of the model's date columns.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
```

It's work fine except for the Eloquent model update function:

```
$contract->update($attributes);
```

Raise an exception with Carbon:

```
  +"message": "Trailing data"
  +"exception": "InvalidArgumentException"
  +"file": "/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php"
  +"line": 917
```

Which is the best way for get custom format of date with Eloquent?

Comment: What you have in `$attributes` variable?

Comment: An array, like:
        [
            'contract_date' => '2020-05-01',
            'contract_end'  => '2020-05-31',
        ];

Comment: are you certain? have you dd($attributes) when you call it?

Comment: Yep, I'm using test cases and debugging. Also, I confirmed they are stored on DB. I've the impression the method update use default format 'U' instead the defined on dateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

**Which is the best way for get custom format of date with Eloquent?**
Laravel $dateFormat was a hit or miss for me as well. I ended up using [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) instead.

In the Model::class

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

// contract_date -- Accessor
public function getContractDateAttribute($value)
{
   return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}

// contract_date -- Mutator
public function setContractDateAttribute($value)
{
   $this->attributes['contract_date'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```